# How to hide unwanted element on the embed website by using script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Faced with necessity to hide unwanted element on embed website. There's piece of HTML code:

```
<section class="class Name" style="display: block;">
```

Problem: Manipulate with CSS does not work due to '`display: block`' written inline in HTML body.

Question: Is there any way how to remove this element OR rewrite '`display: block`' TO '`display: none`' with Java script OR jQuery?

May be it worth, here's exact piece of code that necessary to rewrite from 'display: block' to 'display: hide':

```
<section class="promotion-block custom-storey no-margin-bottom multi-lang-default en ru pt es fr" style="display: block;">
```

The task is to add some script that will force native code to be rewritten from `display: block;` to `display: hide;`

Thanks!

Comment: $('section.className').hide(); see here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Or $('section.className').css('display','none');

Comment: what you mean, embeded website ? does that mean via `iframe`? if it's not on via iframe you can do `jQuery('.classname').remove();` to remove element from DOM

Comment: However the above two methods will just hide the element but it still available in the DOM. If you want to remove the element from the DOM use this $('section.className').remove();

Comment: RE: 'embed website' it does mean that the side embed / built into Android app and used as mobile application, but original site has certain blocks (such as promo ads area) that necessary to remove from that app.

Those 'ads area' managed by 'display: block' code written inline in HTML body, as shown above.

So, the task to hide unwanted Ads area from the app by adding Java script OR jQuery script into application.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try in java script..

```
document.getElementById('#ElementId').style.display = 'block';//show    
document.getElementById('#ElementId').style.display = 'none';//hide
```

and with jQuery..

```
$("#ElementId").hide();
$("#ElementId").show();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for the help, but does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be some user interaction to make to toggle between being visible and hidden, i will be assuming it to be a click event on a button with id `button`.

```
<script>
     var buttonEL = document.getElementById("button");
     buttonEL.addEventListener("click" function(){document.getElementsByClass("className")[0].style.display = "none";});
</script>
```

or if your set up requires it to be hidden always just have

```
document.getElementsByClass("className")[0].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: User interraction unacceptable in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: add `<script>document.getElementsByClass("className")[0].style.display = "none";</script>` at the bottom, if there are more elements with the same className use a for loop (i will edit my answer if so)

Comment: By bottom i mean just before the closing  body tag </body>

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need to manipulate the JavaScript style proprieties here did you try this:

```
element.style.display = 'none';           // Hide
element.style.display = 'block';          // Show
element.style.display = 'inline';         // Show
element.style.display = 'inline-block';   // Show
```

remember to create an getelementID(div ID around or into section tag)

```
function hide (elements) {
  elements = elements.length ? elements : [elements];
  for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
    elements[index].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

in JQuery use this to hidden/show div block:

```
$(".divIDClass").hide(); // hidden

$(".divIDClass").hide(); // show
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to hide the section

1. override the style attribute.
2. Use jQuery hide() and show()

If the section is dynamic loaded then you have to use jquery on function .

code:

1. $(document).on('load','section[class="class Name"]',function()
   {
   $(this).css('style','display:none');
   });
2. $(document).on('load','section[class="class Name"]',function()
   {
   $(this).hide();
   });

If not dynamic loaded

code:

1. $('section[class="class Name"]').css('style','display:none');
2. $('section[class="class Name"]').hide();

Comment: Thank you for the help, but does not work unfortunately.